# Lotusscript sort 3 Text-Lists. Text-List 2 & 3 will follow sorting of Text-List 1

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

In my document I have 3 Text-List fields. I can sort the first Text-List ascending just fine. But how do I make Text-List 2 & 3 follow the final sorting of Text-List 1? Something like the following:

Before sorting:

Text-List 1 (C, A, D, B), Text-List 2 (W, X, Y, Z), Text-List 3 (L, I, S, T)

After sorting (I'd want it to be like the following):

Text-List 1 (A, B, C, D), Text-List 2 (X, Z, W, Y), Text-List 3 (I, T, L, S)

Is there any way to achieve this? I tried putting each of the Text-List into array but it's too much problem for me to compare which element in Text-List 1 should came first while keeping track of the index in a temporary variable and using the index to re-sort Text-List 2 & 3 by transferring their element into their respective second temporary array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have

- three fields in your document List1, List2 and List3
- they have all the same amount of list elements
- they won't be together larger then 64K

then you can concatenate the lists, sort and write them back to fields with the help of Evaluate:

```vb
vResult = Evaluate(|
    _Delimiter := "#";
    _ListAll := @Sort(List1 + _Delimiter + List2 + _Delimiter + List3);
    FIELD List1 := @Word(_ListAll; _Delimiter; 1);
    FIELD List2 := @Word(_ListAll; _Delimiter; 2);
    FIELD List3 := @Word(_ListAll; _Delimiter; 3);
    ""|, doc)
```

Choose a delimiter which won't be appear in lists.

Comment: The best solution. In such cases I use "#%$" as delimiter, can't imagine situation when it could appear in normal text. :)

Comment: This is the answer that I wanted to give, but I forgot about @Word!  Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are a lot of sort algorithms for LotusScript out there. but your problem can be easily solved using an evaluate statement:

```
Dim doc as NotesDocument
'- somehow set the doc
Dim varResult as Variant

varResult = Evaluate({@Sort(Fieldlist1) : @Sort(Fieldlist2) : @Sort(Fieldlist3)}, doc)
```

If you do not want to use evaluate, you can implement a sort- algorithm of your choice and do something like:

```
Dim varResult as Variant

VarResult = YourSortFunction(doc.Fieldlist1)
VarResult = ArrayAppend( VarResult,YourSortFunction(doc.Fieldlist2) )
VarResult = ArrayAppend( VarResult,YourSortFunction(doc.Fieldlist3) )
```

Comment: If I use the Evaluate code that you provide, will it automatically amend the value at the background? (doc.Replaceitemvalue?) Which resulting Fieldlist did the varResult refer to? I'm assuming that varResult only have the value of the sorted Fieldlist1, but do I need to still do a doc.Replaceitemvalue("Fieldlist1", varResult)?

Comment: Maybe I need to re-clarify my requirements, Text-List 2 & 3 may not necessarily like the example like I've given. It could be anything that we can't easily sort just by looking. It could be names for Text-List 2 like (John Smith, John Wayne, Sean Michael, Simon Anderson). Which means initially John Smith is tied to Text-List's 1 "C", John Wayne is "A" and so on. And in the end Text-List 2 will be (John Wayne, Simon Anderson, John Smith, Sean Michael).

Comment: Something that might be more familiar is the column sorting in Microsoft Excel where you are asked whether to expand the sorting to the other columns also.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom class:

```
  public class TripleText

   private v1 as string
   private v2 as string
   private v3 as string

   sub new(s1 as string, s2 as string, s3 as string)
     v1 = s1
     v2 = s2
     v3 = s3
   end sub

   property get value1 as string
    value1 = v1
   end property

   property get value2 as string
    value2 = v2
   end property

   property get value3 as string
    value3 = v3
   end property

  end class
```

Then I would create an array:

```
  dim sortMe(4) as TripleText
```

Populate it:

```
  dim text1 as variant
  dim text2 as variant
  dim text3 as variant

  text1 = doc.getItemValue("textList1")
  text2 = doc.getItemValue("textList2")
  text3 = doc.getItemValue("textList3")

  for i = 0 to 4
   sortMe(i) = new TripleText(text1(i),text2(i),text3(i))
  next
```

Now all you have to do is sort SortMe array.  You can find a sample QuickSort implementation in LotusScript [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21109011), and after some rewriting to adapt it to work with TripleText you will just call it:

dim Sorted(4) as TripleText
   Sorted = QuickSort(SortMe)

The linked QuickSort implementation sorts an array of strings, and you have an array of TripleText. That's why I say there will be some re-writing to adapt it, but it will be quite easy to modify the code so that it takes a TripleText array and sorts it based on the value1 property.  I.e., I'm not going to rewrite all that code for you, but the key is that instead of doing comparisons like this:

```
If sA(i) < PivotValue Then
```

You would do them like this:

```
If TT(i).value1 < PivotValue Then
```

The swaps, or course, deal with the entire TripleText object containing all three values, not just value1.

(I renamed SA to TT becuase I figure SA stood for 'string array'.  If I were going to steal this code, I would definitely bother to rename things to make it suit my purposes.)

Finally, once you've called your QuickSort and gotten your SortMe array in the correct order, you just need to extract the values out of the array of TripleText back into string arrays, and then use ReplaceItemValue to put those string arrays back to the NotesItems:

```
  for i = 0 to 4
   text1(i) = sortMe(i).value1
   text2(i) = sortMe(i).value2
   text3(i) = sortMe(i).value3
  next
  doc.ReplaceItemValue("TextList1",text1)
  doc.ReplaceItemValue("TextList2",text2)
  doc.ReplaceItemValue("TextList3",text3)
```